# Open Source Database Proxies?

Tags: sql-server, database, oracle, security, proxy

Does anyone know of an open source database proxy where it can serve as an intermediary between a closed-source client application and either a SQL server and/or Oracle database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, I have not found a proxy for an Oracle database. Therefore, I took matters into my own hands. A valuable source of this information can be found in [Oracle's JDBC drivers](http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/tech/java/sqlj_jdbc/htdocs/jdbc_111060.html). As well, I recommend using [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to analyze the basic network traffic between your client and an existing database (although it only understands the basic of the protocol, you can get a feel for the general packet structure).

I don't know what you expect your proxy to do, so I will give you a summary of what I needed mine to do. Mine was supposed to allow clients to connect to my proxy server using a user name, password and SID that could be completely different from the real Oracle server. For example, if a client connected to the proxy as user name `corner`, password `gas` and SID `DOGRIVER`, the proxy would translate it to user name `scott`, password `tiger` and SID `PROD` on the real server.

I have managed to create a proxy that works with 10g databases. With a tiny bit of work, it can be modified to work with 11i. With some more intensive work, it can work with 9i. Most information I needed was found in the JDBC drivers and Wireshark mentioned earlier, but I am willing to share my code if you're interested.

Comment: Absolutely would be interested in seeing your code. I wanted to use it for the same challenge.

Comment: Fair enough, I will have to clean it up.

Comment: Any news on this? I'm not personnally interested but suspect many people would be...

Comment: @reiniero do you have the code? I have the exact same requirement

Comment: @AdamPaynter i also have similar requirement for sql server. can u share the code, if possible